# How to set html { display:none; } for a page embedded in an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clickjacking

Here is the test page I have. On this page there is an iFrame with another page from my site embedded.

```
 <html> 
 <head> 
 <title>Clickjack test page</title> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
 <p>Website is not vulnerable to clickjacking.</p> 
 <iframe src="admin.html" width="500" height="500" id="iframe"></iframe>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Here is the JavaScript I am using. this code is in admin.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.location != window.parent.location){
    // is within an iframe
     /* $("iframe").bind('load', function(){
     $("iframe").contents().find("body").css('display', 'none');
     $(this).hide();
   });  */
}

else {
    // not within an iframe
}
</script>
```

The goal here:

When you visit the ClickJacking test page, the html within the iframe should be set to display: none.

I do not want anyone to be able to see the admin page within the iframe.

As you can see, I have several commented out attempts. But no matter what I do, the admin.html is still visible.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: _"to see the admin page within the iframe"_ is this your way of preventing administrative access in case someone engineered a page to display yours within an iframe?

Comment: Maybe your boolean needs to be changed to (top !== self)